# Setting a \newif to false ignored on first check in custom itemize environment

Tags: environments, conditionals, itemize

I'm working on a document template in which I have some nested itemize lists which I need to add some commands before and after each list element.

To accomplish this, I've created a new environment with the `\newenvironment` command, which I'll call `tlist` which is a wrapper around the `itemize` environment, and also created a new command called `\titem` which is a wrapper around the `\item` command.

I'm then using a `\newif` to detect whether or not an item has been opened and closed to allow list nesting without needing anything after the `\titem`. A MWE is shown below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% Keep track of whether we are in a titem
\newif\ifistitemopen

% TList environment
\newenvironment{tlist}{
    % Begin list
    \begin{itemize}
    % Check if an item is open already
\ifistitemopen
    % Must be in a nested list. Close just the body
    \item close by tlist begin
\fi
    % No item is open
    \istitemopenfalse
}{
    % No item is open
    \ifistitemopen
        % Close previous list item if open
        \item close by tlist end
        \istitemopenfalse
    \fi
    % End list
    \end{itemize}
}

% New user command \titem replaces \item
\newcommand{\titem}{
\ifistitemopen
    % Close previous list item if open
    \item close by new item
\fi
    \istitemopentrue
    % Open new list item
    \item open by new item
    \item
}

\begin{document}


\textbf{Bad Example 1:}

\begin{tlist}
    \titem Foo
    
    \begin{tlist}
        \titem Bar
    \end{tlist}
    
\end{tlist}

\textbf{Bad Example 2:}

\begin{tlist}
    \titem Foo
    
    \begin{tlist}
        \titem Bar
    \end{tlist}
    
    \titem Fizz
    
\end{tlist}

\end{document}
```

Currently this is mostly working, except for reasons I can't fathom the first time the `\if...` is checked after it has been set false seems to detect it as true. To try and visualise this, I've added some extra `\item` commands into the code to print out when things are happening. I've shown two examples, where the `if` is checked were even though it should be false, an `\item` is output as if it were true - highlighted on the image below.

[image: Bad Examples with extra close item]

I'm not an expert on LaTeX, so any advice as to why this is happening and how I can fix it would be greatly received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it works with counters and not with conditionals is that counters are acted on *globally* (transcending the group in which they are set in, and environments form groups).

To the contrary, `\newif` makes the `\...false` and `\...true` commands to only act *locally*, so their effect ends with the group where they appear. You can fix them by hand, if you want that the commands act globally.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% Keep track of whether we are in a titem
\newif\ifistitemopen
% redefine the associated commands to act globally
\def\istitemopentrue{\global\let\ifistitemopen\iftrue}
\def\istitemopenfalse{\global\let\ifistitemopen\iffalse}

% TList environment
\newenvironment{tlist}{%
    % Begin list
    \begin{itemize}
    % Check if an item is open already
\ifistitemopen
    % Must be in a nested list. Close just the body
    \item close by tlist begin
\fi
    % No item is open
    \istitemopenfalse
}{%
    % No item is open
    \ifistitemopen
        % Close previous list item if open
        \item close by tlist end
        \istitemopenfalse
    \fi
    % End list
    \end{itemize}
}

% New user command \titem replaces \item
\newcommand{\titem}{%
\ifistitemopen
    % Close previous list item if open
    \item close by new item
\fi
    \istitemopentrue
    % Open new list item
    \item open by new item
    \item
}

\begin{document}


\textbf{Bad Example 1:}

\begin{tlist}
    \titem Foo
    
    \begin{tlist}
        \titem Bar
    \end{tlist}
    
\end{tlist}

\textbf{Bad Example 2:}

\begin{tlist}
    \titem Foo
    
    \begin{tlist}
        \titem Bar
    \end{tlist}
    
    \titem Fizz
    
\end{tlist}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, do `\global\istitemopentrue` and `\global\istitemopenfalse` in the code.

[image]

Comment: Cheers, that makes a lot of sense. I thought I was going mad for a while there. I'll change back to using the global if as it seems a tad cleaner than a counter going from 0 to 1 and back again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the `\newif` wasn't working as expected, but I've found a work around using a counter:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% Keep track of whether we are in a titem
\newcounter{titemopencount}
\setcounter{titemopencount}{0}

% TList environment
\newenvironment{tlist}{
    % Begin list
    \begin{itemize}
    % Check if an item is open already
\ifnum\the\value{titemopencount}>0
    % Must be in a nested list. Close just the body
    \item close by tlist begin
    \addtocounter{titemopencount}{-1}
\fi
    % No item is open
}{
    % No item is open
    \ifnum\the\value{titemopencount}>0
        % Close previous list item if open
        \item close by tlist end
        \addtocounter{titemopencount}{-1}
    \fi
    % End list
    \end{itemize}
}

% New user command \titem replaces \item
\newcommand{\titem}{
\ifnum\the\value{titemopencount}>0
    % Close previous list item if open
    \item close by new item
    \addtocounter{titemopencount}{-1}
\fi
    \addtocounter{titemopencount}{1}
    % Open new list item
    \item open by new item
    \item
}

\begin{document}


\textbf{Good Example 1:}

\begin{tlist}
    \titem Foo
    
    \begin{tlist}
        \titem Bar
    \end{tlist}
    
\end{tlist}

\textbf{Good Example 2:}

\begin{tlist}
    \titem Foo
    
    \begin{tlist}
        \titem Bar
    \end{tlist}
    
    \titem Fizz
    
\end{tlist}

\end{document}
```

Which now produces:

[image: Good Example]